# AWK - how to improve this example with gsub?

Tags: awk, gsub

I have a file:

```
one one one
one one
one one
one
one
one
```

This command replaced 5 times "one", "three"

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; NF>=i; i++)if($i~/one/)a++}{if(a<=5) gsub("one", "three"); print }' file

three three three
three three
one one
one
one
one
```

Now the same thing, but 6 times:

```
$ awk '{for(i=1; NF>=i; i++)if($i~/one/)a++}{if(a<=6) gsub("one", "three"); print }' file

three three three
three three
one one
one
one
one
```

How to improve the above example? I want this result:

```
three three three
three three
three one
one
one
one
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {if ($i ~ /one/) {a++; if(a <= 6) sub("one", "three", $i)}}; print}'
```

Comment: I have a question.  Is it necessary to use the above example, write `sub("one", "three", $i)` 

instead of : 

`sub("one", "three")` ?

Thank you.

Comment: @Tedee12345: if you don't specify the field (or something else such as a variable), then `$0` is used by default. `sub()` only replaces the first instance so you'd never get "three three" on your second line with the default of `$0`. `gsub()` with the default of `$0` wouldn't allow you to have "three one" on the third line since it'd give you "three three" since it's global. You could still use `gsub` like this: `gsub("one", "three", 1)` if you wanted "oneoneone one" to become "threethreethree one" since the "global" would only be applied to field 1.

Comment: Otherwise, for simple replacements (as it *appears* that you're doing in your question, you don't need `sub` or `gsub` at all. You could do a direct assignment `if(a <= 6) {$i = "three"}`.